# What does "net_ratelimit: 44 callbacks suppressed" mean on a linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-networking

I'm trying to tune Snort performance on a Debian based router.  I was seeing stuff like:

```
snort packet recv contents failure: No buffer space available
```

So I upped the buffers to 8M and when that didn't work I tried 16M, per the tuning guide at http://fasterdata.es.net/fasterdata/host-tuning/linux/:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
# Increase TCP Buffers to 16 MB
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default='16777216'
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default='16777216'
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max='16777216'
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max='16777216'
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='1048576 4194304 16777216'
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='1048576 4194304 16777216'
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog='30000'
exit 0
```

Now I don't see the "no buffer space" log entry, but I've got a new one:

```
net_ratelimit: 44 callbacks suppressed
```

The only other messages from the same time frame are these martians, maybe that's what's being suppressed?

```
Jun  4 07:09:36 ilium ntpd_intres[3575]: host name not found: 0.us.pool.ntp.org
Jun  4 14:17:36 ilium kernel: [25743.259951] net_ratelimit: 44 callbacks suppressed
Jun  4 14:17:36 ilium kernel: [25743.259955] martian source 216.59.11.21 from 127.0.0.1, on dev eth0
Jun  4 14:17:36 ilium kernel: [25743.259956] ll header: 00:30:48:7c:f8:10:00:24:c4:49:8d:00:08:00
Jun  4 14:17:58 ilium kernel: [25765.055449] martian source 216.59.11.21 from 127.0.0.1, on dev eth0
Jun  4 14:17:58 ilium kernel: [25765.055451] ll header: 00:30:48:7c:f8:10:00:24:c4:49:8d:00:08:00
Jun  4 14:18:43 ilium kernel: [25809.998978] martian source 216.59.11.21 from 127.0.0.1, on dev eth0
Jun  4 14:18:43 ilium kernel: [25809.998980] ll header: 00:30:48:7c:f8:10:00:24:c4:49:8d:00:08:00
Jun  4 14:24:11 ilium kernel: [26138.700143] martian source 216.59.11.71 from 127.0.0.1, on dev eth0
Jun  4 14:24:11 ilium kernel: [26138.700145] ll header: 00:30:48:7c:f8:10:00:24:c4:49:8d:00:08:00
Jun  4 14:28:42 ilium kernel: [26409.130701] martian source 216.59.11.71 from 127.0.0.1, on dev eth0
Jun  4 14:28:42 ilium kernel: [26409.130703] ll header: 00:30:48:7c:f8:10:00:24:c4:49:8d:00:08:00
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

'`net_ratelimit()`' is used to limit syslog messages from kernel.
This "callbacks suppressed" message implies it suppressed a bulk of 44 syslog messages.
This is an attempt to avoid loading your syslog logging path.

Here is the source reference if you are interested,
[FreeBSD/Linux Kernel Cross Reference; sys/net/core/utils.c](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/core/utils.c?v=linux-2.6),
It calls [sys/lib/ratelimit.c](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/lib/ratelimit.c?v=linux-2.6) -- `___ratelimit()`

You might want to investigate your "[martian source](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1812/123.htm)",
but if you ignore it I guess, the ratelimit will handle the logs
(it is usually a good idea to fix unknown log sources tho).

In your case it appears like your [Martian Packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet) are,

> An incoming or outgoing packet whose **source** or destination address is in the range 127.0.0.0/8, which is reserved for loopback within the host.

Comment: this is good reading too: http://zszsit.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/ratelimit-callbacks-suppressed.html a good troubleshooting of `__ratelimit: # callbacks supressed`